How to animate the rotation of multiple objects at different orientations?
I want to animate the propellors on this model of a quadcopter. Each of the blades and motor sets are oriented at different angles compared to each other.
I need to parent two blades and a motor on each set, then add a null at precisely their central position, then control them all?
Is there an easy way to create a single null to control the rotation of all four blades from a single controller?



Add a driver to the rotation channel?

The issue is that the orientation isn't straight up - I'm not sure how to achieve that, as all the angles are off. I can't just put #frame*0.01 on the z-axis for example, and I'd like to know how to apply that rotation to all of them at once, so I don't have to animate each rotor individually

As long as the rotation order is zxy/zyx, changing their z value should behave the same on all four instances. (If not, pleas upload a screenshot with the objects axes visualized.)

You need to parent the motor/blades while they are still aligned with the world's axes to an empty for example, then orient the empty to the angles the motor should have, then you can rotate the blades on the Z axis locally to the empty's axes.

parent each blade to an empty, tilt the empties the way you want, use any kind of object as target to make the other rotate on their own axis with the help of some Copy Rotation constraints?

Thank you so much! It worked! If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll label it solved! I don't quite understand why parenting the rotors to the motor, then adding a 'Copy Rotation' constraint to the motor doesn't work, but adding a new object, and pairing the rotors and motor to that object does. The Copy Rotation constraint with the Owner set to Local Space was the key to solving it. Many thanks!
